# Python beautifulSoup webpage decode problem

Tags: python, web-scraping, unicode, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** the following two pages using beautifulSoap4

- https://30nama.kim/top/imdb-movie.html
- https://30nama.kim/top/30nama-movie.html

Both have the same HTML structure.
When I load the first webpage, it's all fine and I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="fa-IR">
 <head>
  <style id="litespeed-optm-css-rules">
   ...
```

But the second webpage output is this:

```
Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
      �[s�Ƶ(��_���!��3�+ E:�|���lmI����.UИ��&amp; ���!���p���'ە�����~��?1��̩� f0�\ q�
<u*q�"�f��v�[�^}��~|�����e����4� 94�,4�pf�cӗ��̣[="%��[iv*#��0�T:P�kŃ��rӴ�" c��gm_vv۾l�gz���_���yˏ�����8�qw��ȳԕ�:h����="" �@��;��tʳ�="" �h�:a�="" ��@fy="">
 =��È�
```

Here is my python code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = 'https://30nama.kim/top/30nama-movie.html'
req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")
print(page_soup.prettify())
```

I don't know what happens to the second page and what do these characters mean. I thought I should try to decode it using utf-8 but it didn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup uses Unicode, Dammit to detect the encoding. This is not always correct.

I sat the encoding manually and it worked:

```
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser", from_encoding="ISO-8859-7")
```